# Diferencias entre métodos, procedimiento, función, para que sirven cada uno y como se declaran en C#

Tags: c#

¿En qué se diferencian los métodos, clases, procedimientos y funciones en C# y cómo se declaran?

Answer (score 19):

- **Procedimiento**: Es un conjunto de instrucciones que cumplen una tarea
- **Función**: Como un procedimiento pero retorna un valor
- **Clase**: Concepto de programación orientada a objetos, es una forma de encapsular funcionalidad, contiene  campos y métodos.
- **Método**: Puede ser un procedimiento o una función, la diferencia es que le pertenece a una clase.

.

```
public class ConsoleTest
{
    public void Saludo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("¡Hola!");
    }

    public int Suma(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo,

- `ConsoleTest` es una clase
- `Saludo` es un método y un procedimiento.  Como no devuelve un valor es tipo `void`
- `Suma` es un método y una función

Answer (score 4):

**Procedimiento, funciones y metodos**

Son basicamente lo mismo solo se diferencian en el nombre segun devuelvan o no un valor de respuesta. Se podria decir que un `Procedimiento` si declaras un metodo como `void`, en cambio es `funcion` si retornan un tipo de dato u objeto
Ambos los declaras como `metodos`

[Métodos (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173114.aspx)

**Clases**

Esta relacionado con la `Programacion orientada a objetos`. Basicamente una clase define un tipo (definiendo propiedades y metodos) al instanciarlo (usando el `new`) creas un objeto.

[Programación orientada a objetos (C# y Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd460654.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Una definición muy general de la diferencia principal entre una **Función** y un **Método** es:

> - Las funciones se definen fuera de las clases.
> - Los métodos se definen dentro de y son parte de las clases.

En realidad son similares funcion o método puede retornar o no un valor.

mientras que un **Procedimiento**: Define varias instrucciones para realizar una tarea.

Comment: El término *función* se utiliza en otros lenguajes como C++ por ejemplo, el equivalente en C# sería un método, por lo tanto tengo entendido que no existen funciones en C#.

Comment: Claro, es un termino general en realidad yo consideraría es lo mismo. He visto que comentan que si no retornan un valor (void) es una función. En realidad un método dentro de una clase podría no retornar un valor.

Comment: Si son lo mismo, ¿cómo se definiría una función fuera de una clase?

Comment: **si comentas que no existen funciones en C#**, entonces la demás preguntas también son erroneas....

Comment: Nop, no digo que no existan :) solo hago referencia a tu respuesta, dices que *Las funciones se definen fuera de las clases.*. Me gustaría ver algún ejemplo ya que a lo mejor me estoy perdiendo de algo.

Comment: es que comentaste "por lo tanto tengo entendido que no existen funciones en C#."

Comment: Eso tengo entendido, ya sea que no existan o que una función y un método para mí es lo mismo, y por lo mismo digo *a lo mejor me estoy perdiendo de algo* :) Un ejemplo podría simplificar todo este embrollo jeje

Answer (score 0):

Usando C siempre se ha hablado de funciones, ya que éstas se definían fuera de la estructura de las clases (de hecho no existían clases, solo estructuras de datos).

Con la llegada de c++ se incorporaron las clases, y a la definición de funciones anidadas en clases se las llamó métodos. Todo con independencia de si devolvían un valor o no.

Tras ésto, los términos método y función se siguieron empleando y los lenguajes de programación fueron evolucionando sin alcanzar un consenso sobre como llamar a este mecanismo.

No se si ésto responde realmente a tu pregunta, lo dejo como información.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que si nos enfocamos en POO,
METODO.- se define como el comportamiento de un objeto,
es el que da vida, respuesta y/o proceso a una peticion que se le realiza a un objeto.
FUNCION.- Es el resultado de un procedimiento, que NO pertecene a un objeto, su comportamiento se centra en el resultado o proceso al que se quiere llegar sin estar atado a un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende del método que use, si usa un procedimiento no devuelve parámetro si una una función devuelve un parámetro. importante solo uno, pero este puede ser una lista de clases, en SQL se le dice procedimientos almacenados a métodos que devuelven no solo un parámetro sin varios.

Answer (score -1):

Opino lo mismo que Jorgesys, método y función es lo mismo; ambos pueden retornar o no un valor. El nombre varía en el lugar que se use, por ejemplo, según la definición expuesta en la página de developer de Mozilla, referente a Javascript"Un valor de propiedad puede ser una función, la cual es conocida entonces como un método del objeto"[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos).

En C# suelo llamar función a lo que está definido por fuera de la clase y método si está definido dentro de la clase. Entendiendo que todo esto es conceptual y desde otros lenguajes pueda definirse de otra manera.

Bibliografía: [Javascript:Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)