# Duda entre función y método en C#

Tags: c#, funciones, método

Estoy aprendiendo C# y tengo una duda con el tema de las clases, los objetos, métodos y funciones.

1. Según tengo entendido un método es un subprograma que realiza una función sin devolver un resultado, mientras que una función se diferencia de un método en que la función sí que devuelve un resultado. ¿Es correcto?

Lo comento porque veo que el profesor indica que lo siguiente es un método y veo que devuelve un valor, por lo que pienso que debe ser una función y no un método dado que devuelve un valor:

```
private int buscarEmpleado(string nombre) {
    int pos = -1, i;
    bool encontrado = false;
    tEmpleado empl;
    i = 0;
    while (i < mLista.Count && !encontrado) {
        empl = (tEmpleado) mLista[i];
        if (empl.Nombre == nombre) {
            pos = i;
            encontrado = true;
        } else
            i++;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

2. Respecto a los objetos, tengo entendido que se inicializan dentro de la clase, pero... ¿se escribe el código de creación del objeto en la clase o en el código del formulario? Según tengo entendido, la creación se escribe en el archivo del código del formulario y la inicialización se escribe en el archivo de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Un método y una función son prácticamente lo mismo la diferencia radica en que un método pertenece a una clase, y si tienes un método que no te devuelve ningún valor, es decir de tipo `void`, a esto se le conoce como procedimiento.

Comment: En el código que nos facilita el profesor, veo que dentro de la clase ha usado funciones (dicho con sus palabras en los comentarios del código). ¿Sería entonces esto correcto? Me refiero a usar funciones dentro de la clase. Por tu comentario entiendo que es incorrecto.

Comment: Comentas también que un método que no devuelve ningún valor se le conoce como procedimiento. ¿Y cómo se conoce a un método que sí que devuelve un valor?

Answer (score 0):

> Según tengo entendido un método es un subprograma que realiza una
>   función sin devolver un resultado, mientras que una función se
>   diferencia de un método en que la función sí que devuelve un
>   resultado. ¿Es correcto?

El retornar un valor no determina a una función o método.

Una definición muy general de la diferencia principal entre una función y un método es:

> - Las funciones se definen fuera de las clases.
> - Los métodos se definen dentro de y son parte de las clases.

---

> Respecto a los objetos, tengo entendido que se inicializan dentro de
>   la clase, pero... ¿se escribe el código de creación del objeto en la
>   clase o en el código del formulario? Según tengo entendido, la
>   creación se escribe en el archivo del código del formulario y la
>   inicialización se escribe en el archivo de la clase.

La creación de los componentes se realiza generalmente en el "código del formulario", especificamente en:

```
 private void InitializeComponent(){
```

pero aquí mismo puedes cambiar sus propiedades para inicializarlo, por ejemplo:

```
   private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        // 
        // Button1
        // 
        this.Button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(455, 313);
        this.Button1.Name = "Button1";
        this.Button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.Button1.TabIndex = 54;
        this.Button1.Text = "Click here!";
        this.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
        ...
        ...
     }
```

de hecho en el archivo de la clase puedes ver que `InitializeComponent()` es llamado al crear el formulario.

Comment: Comentas que:

"La diferencia principal entre una función y un método es:

Las funciones se definen fuera de las clases.
Los métodos se definen dentro de y son parte de las clases."

Por lo que entiendo que una función se definen fuera de las clases. Pero en cambio, observando las respuestas del enlace (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7403/diferencias-entre-m%C3%A9todos-procedimiento-funci%C3%B3n-para-que-sirven-cada-uno-y-co), pone que:

"Método: Puede ser un procedimiento o una función, la diferencia es que le pertenece a una clase."

Comment: Ahora veo la respuesta, si defines una función dentro de una clase puede considerarse como método de la clase.  Si esta fuera se consideraría una funcion.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Entonces entiendo que el profesor se ha equivocado dado que dentro de la clase explica que está usando una función (cuando en realidad se trata de un método).

Comment: @RichardSteele en realidad son equivalentes, simplemente que la denominación de función o método regularmente no es aplicada.