# Funcion Random de Manera Adecuada

Tags: c#, funciones, unity3d, random, diseño-de-clases

Como puedo usar la función `Random` en C# usando dos funciones, la primera función es el daño mínimo del jugador, y la segunda el daño máximo que puede realizar un jugador, mi idea es usar la función `Random`, llamando a ambas funciones min. y max. y en base al rango de estas muestre el número aleatorio, sin embargo no me funciona, adjunto mi código que es una función de consola.

PD: Dejé el código que no funciona comentado.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {   


        //Metodos para devolver un valor

        static int DanoMinMeleeDistance(int STR, int DEX, int WeaponATK)
        {
            int DanoMinMeleeDistance = ((STR+DEX)/2)+WeaponATK;
            return DanoMinMeleeDistance;
        }
        static int DanoMaxMelee(int STR, int DEX, int WeaponATK)
        {
            int DanoMaxMelee = STR+WeaponATK+(DEX/2);
            return DanoMaxMelee;
        }

       /* static int DanoAleatorio(Random rnd, int DanoMaxMelee, int DanoMinMeleeDistance) {

            int DanoAleatorio = rnd.Next(DanoMinMeleeDistance, DanoMaxMelee);
            return DanoAleatorio;


        }*/

        // Main el principal
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int STR, DEX, WeaponATK;
            Console.Write("INGRESE PRIMER VALOR: ");
            STR = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("INGRESE SEGUNDO VALOR: ");
            DEX = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("INGRESE TERCER VALOR: ");
            WeaponATK = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("1º) Daño Minimo" + "\n" + "2º) Daño Maximo" + "\n" + "3º) Daño Aleatorio <strong>\n");
            Console.Write("Seleccione una opción: ");



            switch (Console.Read())
            {
                case '1':
                    Console.Write("Daño Minimo = " + DanoMinMeleeDistance(STR, DEX, WeaponATK));
                    // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Console.Write("Daño Maximo = " + DanoMaxMelee(STR, DEX, WeaponATK));
                    // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos // 
                    break;

                /*case '3':
                    Console.Write("El numero aleatorio es" + DanoAleatorio()*/
            }
            Console.ReadKey(); // Un pausee para presionar la tecla
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Que quiere decir no me funciona?

Comment: Que el código que está comentado, lanza error y no genera su cometido

Comment: Que error? sera que esa funcion no existe?

Comment: cuando intento agregar las funciones a la funcion aleatorio, no me los toma.

Comment: que funciones? que error te tira?

Answer (score 1):

El error en tu codigo esta en como llamas a tu metodo **'DanoAleatorio'**.
Si ves bien, tu metodo recibe 3 parametros  **(Random rnd, int DanoMaxMelee, int DanoMinMeleeDistance)** , pero estas llamando a la funcion sin ningun parametro y esto ocaciona el error...

Por otro lado, deberias definir que Random utilizar, por mi experiencia solo use 2, mira el siguiente codigo

Ejemplo de como usar random de una clase estatica:

```
public int DanoAleatorio(int min, int max)
{
   return Random.Range(min, max); //Metodo estatico
}

 //Como usarlo
 int numero = DanoAleatorio(123, 456);
```

[Link a este random](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

Otra forma de hacer numeros random, creando una instancia de la clase:

```
Random random = new Random(); //Este es el que trae por defecto .net, y se necesita una instancia para generar numeros
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
```

Para mas informacion sobre funciones y metodos, consulta [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7403/diferencias-entre-m%C3%A9todos-procedimiento-funci%C3%B3n-para-que-sirven-cada-uno-y-co)

Espero haberte ayudado!

---

***Edicion:***

La funcion Random, es una funcion pseudo-aleatoria (podes buscar info aca en el sitio, hay varias preguntas al respecto). Cuando definís un objeto de tipo random, se inicializa con un valor. 
Cuando hace el next, vos le podes decir entre que valores queres que te devuelva el proximo numero, pasandole una cota minima y una maxima:

```
random.Next(min,max);
```

Lo que estas haciendo en tu codigo esta bien, salvo que estas olvidando pasarle un objeto del tipo random. Antes de tu llamada, agrega:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

y despues hace tu llamada de la siguiente forma:

```
DanoAleatorio(rnd,DanoMinMeleeDistance(STR, DEX, WeaponATK),DanoMaxMelee(STR, DEX, WeaponATK))
```

o para que se vea mejor:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int min = DanoMinMeleeDistance(STR, DEX, WeaponATK);
int max = DanoMaxMelee(STR, DEX, WeaponATK);
DanoAleatorio(rnd,min,max);
```

---

***Gracias @gbianchi por la edicion y colaboracion!***

Comment: El problema no es ese (porque su codigo lo tiene bien puesto eso). Fijate que le estamos pidiendo que agregue que error le da.

Comment: Su codigo esta mal, fijate como llama a su funcion, su DanoAleatorio recive 3 parametros, y lo llama sin parametros... , por eso mismo le puse la misma funcion bien hecha

Comment: Ese es su error, no el random ;) pero estaria muy bueno que la pregunta estuviera completa y clara antes de contestarla. Porque aca el problema no es el random, si no el desconocimiento de pasaje de parametros a funciones

Comment: Claro, tenes razon, ya edito mi pregunta y aclaro el por que, se me escapo ese gran detalle

Comment: fijate que en otros casos si pasa los parametros. Entonces hay otro problema aca.. porque arriba los pasa y abajo no? por eso tantas preguntas sobre la pregunta.. para ver donde esta el real problema. Igual lo que venis contestando esta genial ;)

Comment: Hola, respondiendo a sus preguntas, lo hice pasandole parametros en DanoAleatorio, pero lo que yo quiero llamar a la hora de hacer random es el resultado de dañoMax y Daño Min y en base a los resultados , que se genere un numero aleatorio. La verdad desconozco como realizar eso, se que es con números, pero yo quería llamar a las funciones.

Comment: Voy a editar tu respuesta para aclararle a OP un poco mas lo que le pasa. @ChristianAndresHyuden fijate a ver si entendes

Comment: Gracias. lo que pasa

Answer (score 0):

lo resolví mostraré paso a paso como lo resolví gracias @gbianchi por la paciencia ahora explico como lo resolví.
Añadí, un método llamado Constantes, aquí le di un valor a cada Variable.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
Luego Añadí la clase Método, donde van todos los cálculos:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final añadí la clase program la cual procede a l llamado y ejecucion de los objetos que declaro en esta misma clase:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al final funciona, sin errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos :3